# How to get a browser alert message with angularjs and nodemailer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to get an alert with after sending an email with nodemailer and not just the [json](/questions/tagged/json) response.  Here is what I have so far:

app.js ([nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs)with [nodemailer](/questions/tagged/nodemailer)module):

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error) => {
if (error) {
  res.sendStatus(500)
} else {
  res.sendStatus(200)
}
transporter.close();
});

});
```

[angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs):

```
$http.post({
  url: '/contactUs',
  data: '',
}).then(
  function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.alert("Message Sent!!")
  },
  function errorCallback(response) {}
)
```

Comment: Not clear which parts work or don't work is alert a function you defined on scope?  If you want to use the regular alert inject $window where you inject $scope and use $window.alert("message sent!!").  Check the network tab to see if the request is sent and response you expect comes back for that request.  Drop a `debugger` word in your success and error callbacks in the angular code and keep the debug panel open to be sure the code is executing.

Comment: Yes all of this is working I just want a user conformation alert message to appear that confirms the message was sent instead of the screen changing to the json status code (200) which as you probably know is 'OK'. Thank you for responding and helping.

Comment: How are you triggering the $http.post call? something is wrong where a link is being called instead of making the XHR request in the background it sounds like, could maybe be response headers issue too but some context on how it's triggered would help debug the front end stuff.

Comment: it is triggered on the frontend by an ng-click="processFrom()" which is the function located in the formController.  Then sent to the backend and posted with "app.post('/contactUs', function(req, res)"

Comment: in the form do you have an action set if so take it off, also on the input make sure it has type="button" they default to "submit" but strange it's hitting the correct endpoint, by default $post is using XHRHttpRequest in the background to do the async call.  If you can't figure it out or get another answer try reproducing your code on plnkr or codepen or jsfiddle.  You could also try stepping into the $http.post call to put some breakpoints in and see what exactly is happening it should be using async though by default as far as I know.

Comment: Yes I did have the action set.  I removed it and will have to try the jsfiddle route. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need to just call `alert("Message Sent")` instead of `$scope.alert("Message Sent")`.

If you want it to be angularized, you can inject `$window` and call `$window.alert("Message Sent")` which will make it easier on you if you're unit testing.

Comment: Ya I tried both of those earlier but after the email is sent it changes to the json sendStatus(200) code, which is ok. It literally goes to a blank white screen with ok in the top left corner. Oh and thank you for responding and helping!

Comment: I had some other code wrong in my controller after I found that your advice was right on point. Thanks!